# Differentiate which queue was called when using wildcards in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, wildcard, consumer

In my application, I am using wildcards in apache camel and I have defined route builder like this:

from("activemq:queue:*.processQueue").bean(beanOne,"someMethod");

While sending the message I will be sending message to "**{uniqueID}.processQueue**" queue so I need to get that **uniqueId** inside **someMethod** of **beanOne**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full queue path is in the `In` message's `JMSDestination` header ( for example the JMSDestination is `queue://test1.processQueue`). You can use string manipulation functions to get the required `uniqueId`.

Example (`uniqueId` will be `test1`):

```
@Handler
public void someMethod(@Header("JMSDestination") String jmsDestination) {
    String uniqueId = jmsDestination.substring("queue://".length(), jmsDestination.indexOf(".processQueue"));
}
```